# What is the test for physical damage from cold weather / frostbite?

Tags: shadowrun-sr5, environmental-hazards

In *Run & Gun*, the consequences of being exposed to temperatures below freezing are described as follow:

> The risk of frostbite begins when a character is exposed to a
>   Moderate or greater severity environment — temperatures below freezing.
>   Each Environmental Severity increases the damage and decreases the
>   duration between tests according to the Frostbite Damage table.

It is followed by a table indicating the damage and duration between tests, depending on the environment's severity.

But... what test? No matter how hard I look, I can't find any test mentioned anywhere. Does it refer to something in another part of the book, or another book?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is likely that the test being referenced is the **Fatigue From Environments** test.  Pg 172<sup>1</sup> of the SR5 core rules  outlines the rules for Fatigue damage and the test to resist, which is Body + Willpower.  It goes on to describe **Fatigue From Environments**, which describes environmental fatigue as another type of fatigue test and which uses the same rules as fatigue from running.

The rules in *Run & Gun* appear to be expanding on this rule, and providing more detail on the fatigue intervals and **Damage Values** for extreme cold (and other environmental conditions). The core rules are vague on the subject, as they provide only a severity and a time interval and use the base 1S DV (then 2S for the second failure, 3S for the third, and so on...) for all environmental fatigue tests regardless of the condition (heat, cold, pollution, radiation, etc.).

---

<sub>1. At least, page 172 in my book -- a friend of mine has a different print edition which has some pages entirely omitted and other pages with different numbers or in different places; Shadowrun is notorious for these types of problems.</sub>

Comment: It is indeed on p172, and as it is exactly the same table format, that's probably it, thanks!